How to parse a dynamic vector instead of a static while comparing in a INDEX function - EXCEL
I'll like to apologize for the vagueness on the title but I didn't find a better way to put this in words
Now, better explaining my question:
I'm creating my own dynamic VLOOKUP to auto completed data in a sheet that match certain criteria from the previous sheet, in that way I'm dynamically filling a whole sheet with data.
Things to consider in the logic of the formula:

To avoid been dealing with switching sheets to select cells I
converted all the needed data into Tables, so I can just call them
by reference.

Table1 is located in sheet1 while the formula and data will be in sheet2

I'm replacing real information with generic names but formula is the same

the static vector is: {"value1","value2","value3"}


The formula I'm using currently using that work, but needs to be improved by replacing the static vector by a dynamic one
INDEX(Table1[RowHeader1],AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Table1[RowHeader1])-ROW(sheet1!$L$4)+1/(Table1[[RowHeader5]:[RowHeader5]]={"value1","value2","value3"})),ROWS(B$4:B4)))

The formula actually works! and yes it do all what I need... but...,  the only issues is that I would prefer that instead to have one static vector {"value1","value2","value3"} I could do references to cells so I can change anytime my filtering values without the need to modifying the formula each time is needed

Why not use the following: INDEX(Table1[RowHeader1],AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Table1[RowHeader1])-ROW(sheet1!$L$4)+1/(Table1[[RowHeader5]:[RowHeader5]]=$X$1:$Z$1)),ROWS(B$4:B4))) where $X$1:$Z$1 refers to {"value1","value2","value3"} you may need to change the cells as per your data.

because it didn't work...
I have tried:
=$X$1:$Z$1 -
=($X$1:$Z$1) -
=($X$1, $Y$1,$Z$1)

@MayukhBhattacharya Thanks!!! I don't know what happens yesterday but in some how once I tried it =$X$1:$Z$1  it didn't work (It was 3AM) , I'm not sure if it was that I select a wrong cell or what I did wrong... but I just tried it again and it just work.....

... and now; someone to produce a valid A to this Q.

What do you mean by it doesn't work? Post some copiable sample data with your expected output
